# React child component doesn't render html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components

Using React 16, trying to create a child component (a simple one) and for some reason, the inner html does not render, but the component tag does when view with dev tools.

My component code is like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Container, Jumbotron, Button, Col, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import './jumbo.css';
import './index.css';


    class custHero extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Jumbotron className="generalView">
              <h1 className="display-3">Customer and Partner Development</h1>
              <p className="lead">Stay connected with your customers with Moneyball and Immerse</p>
            </Jumbotron>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default custHero;
```

I bring it into the other view/component like:

```
import custHero from './jumboCustomer';
```

then, where I want child component to render:

```
<custHero/>
```

It should simply render the component contents within the child div. What am I missing here for something like this?

The entire component I am trying to bring this child component into:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Container,
    Jumbotron, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText, Tooltip, Col, Row, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem } from 'reactstrap';
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';
import Users from "./Users";
import './index.css';
import './ConnCust.css';
import custHere from 'jumboCustomer'

class ConnCustIm extends Component {

    state = {
        date: new Date(),
    }

    onChange = Date => this.setState({ Date })

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Breadcrumb className="custBread" tag="nav">
            <BreadcrumbItem className="custBread" tag="a" href="#">Home</BreadcrumbItem>
            <BreadcrumbItem className="custBread" active>Connect with Customers</BreadcrumbItem>
        </Breadcrumb>
        <custHero />
        <Container fluid="true">
            <Form className="cenForm">
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="custName" className="inputHead">* Company Name</Label>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="custName" id="custName" placeholder="enter the name of the company you want to visit" />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="custTech" className="inputHead">* Technology</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="custTech" id="custTech" placeholder="enter the technologies you want to see in action: OMS, Azure Stack, IoT" />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="custPurpose" className="inputHead">* Purpose</Label>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="custPurpose" id="custPurpose" placeholder="tell us what you want to see or learn" />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="custLocale" className="inputHead">Company Location</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="custLocale" id="custLocale" placeholder="street address or city/state/country" />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="coNeed" className="inputHead">Companies</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="coNeed" id="coNeed" placeholder="Boeing, Ford, General Electric" />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="coNeed" className="inputHead">Start Date for Visit</Label>
                    <DatePicker
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        value={this.state.date}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup tag="fieldset">
                <Label className="inputHead">Do you want customer onsite or remotely?</Label>
                    <FormGroup check>
                        <Label className="custList" check>
                            <Input type="checkbox" name="custVisitType" />
                            Onsite
                        </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup check>
                        <Label className="custList" check>
                            <Input type="checkbox" name="custVisitType" />
                            Remotely
                        </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="custComments" className="inputHead">Comments</Label>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="custComments" id="custComments" placeholder="anything else do you want to tell us" />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Button id="submitButton"><NavLink to="/ConfirmIm">Submit</NavLink></Button>
                </FormGroup>
            </Form>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ConnCustIm;
```

Thanks much.

**EDIT:**

changed child to the following, and it works fine.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container, Jumbotron, Button, Col, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import './jumbo.css';
import './index.css';

export const CustHero = () =>
  <Jumbotron className="customerView">
    <h1 className="display-3">Customer and Partner Development test</h1>
    <p className="lead">Stay connected with your customers with Moneyball and Immerse</p>
  </Jumbotron>
```

Comment: there is no errors could you also give the component where you are using the custHero, since the given details are not enough

Comment: @Akhileshkrishnan - added additional component code. Yeah, still not seeing why this is not rendering. Am sure it is something simple.

Comment: So, what does `Jumbotron` do or how does it renders its children?

Comment: Jumobotron is used in Bootstrap framework. In this case, I am using reactstrap for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that react components should be starting with a capital letter or they are confused with custom html tags in JSX.

Please, try updating like this: `class CustHero extends Component {`, `export default CustHero;`, `import CustHero from './jumboCustomer';`, `<CustHero/>`.

You can notice that all other components that you are using are also capitalised, i.e. `Jumbotron`, `Button`, `Row` and so on.

P.S. Also, it seems there is a typo in your parent component now: `import custHere from 'jumboCustomer'`.

Comment: Weird, not working that way, but if I simply change the child component file as const and export that, it is fine. Even fixing typo and capitalizing didn't help. See edit in post to what works. Still wouldn't mind further explanation on the issue with it.

Comment: Hm, to me it seems that it works with capitalising your initial example. Here's a link to a sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-am418d